# Omnipotence and Omniscience

Tags: sources-mekorot, theology

Where was it first claimed that God is omnipotent or omniscient?

Did God or an authorized prophet ever actually make this claim?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31941/ancient-texts-claiming-that-g-d-is-perfect#comment82867_31941

Answer (score 1):

Sources for G-d's  omnipotence & omniscience are:

1) **Divine omnipotence.**
[From Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_in_Judaism)

> The Jewish belief in God's omnipotence is rooted in the Bible:
>
> 'Why did Sarah laugh, and say "Shall I indeed bear a child now that I
>   am old?" Is anything too hard for the Lord?'"[Gen. 18:13-3] “Attribute
>   to the Lord all glory and power.”[Ps. 29]

The quote “Is anything too hard for the Lord?” is early and demonstrates omnipotence. (I would have thought that the creation of the world is sufficient demonstration.)

2) **Divine  omniscience.**
[From Aish.com quoting the Rambam](http://www.aish.com/sp/ph/48925687.html)

> The Almighty knows the actions of people and does not ignore them. [It
>   is] not like those who say (Ezekiel 8:12), "God has abandoned the
>   land," but rather like [the Scriptures that attest to His scrutiny],
>   as it says (Genesis 6:5), "The Almighty saw that there was great evil
>   perpetrated by man in the land..." and (Genesis 18:20), "The Almighty
>   said, 'The cry of Sodom and Gemorrah is great...' " All this attests
>   to this principle.

G-d's knowledge of the evils demonstrates His omniscience.

3) **For more detail** see Derekh Hashem, “The Way of G-d” translated by Aryeh Kaplan, Chap 1, para 2,
4)

> The only thing that we can know about Him is that he is perfect in
>   every possible way and devoid of every conceivable deficiency.

Omniscience and omnipotence are included in “ devoid of every conceivable deficiency”.

(Sources are Rambam Yad Yesodei HaTorah 2:8, Saadia Gaon Emunos vedeyos 1:4 and Joseph Albo, Ikkarim 2:1. You would have to look these up to find what they base themselves on.)

Comment: How would creation of the world imply omnipotence?? It implies an ability to create a world like ours. Ps 29 also seems rather irrelevant. "G-d's knowledge of the evils demonstrates His omniscience." I don't follow that at all. It only implies He knew of those evils.

Comment: The omnipotent part is answered well, but the omniscient part is less so, unless one considers that omniscience is one of the powers of omnipotence.